# Can't remove replication controller manager within deployment in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am having a bit of a problem. I deleted a pod of a replication controller and now I want to recreate it. I tried:

```
kubectl create -f kube-controller-manager.yaml
Error from server: error when creating "kube-controller-manager.yaml": deployments.extensions "kube-controller-manager" already exists
```

So figured to:

```
kubectl delete deployment kube-controller-manager --namespace=kube-system -v=8
```

Which circles for a while giving this response:

```
GET https://k8s-k8s.westfield.io:443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments/kube-controller-manager
I0112 17:33:53.334288   44607 round_trippers.go:303] Request Headers:
I0112 17:33:53.334301   44607 round_trippers.go:306]     Accept: application/json, */*
I0112 17:33:53.334310   44607 round_trippers.go:306]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.4.7 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/92b4f97
I0112 17:33:53.369422   44607 round_trippers.go:321] Response Status: 200 OK in 35 milliseconds
I0112 17:33:53.369445   44607 round_trippers.go:324] Response Headers:
I0112 17:33:53.369450   44607 round_trippers.go:327]     Content-Type: application/json
I0112 17:33:53.369454   44607 round_trippers.go:327]     Date: Fri, 13 Jan 2017 01:33:53 GMT
I0112 17:33:53.369457   44607 round_trippers.go:327]     Content-Length: 1688
I0112 17:33:53.369518   44607 request.go:908] Response Body: {"kind":"Deployment","apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","metadata":{"name":"kube-controller-manager","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments/kube-controller-manager","uid":"830c83d0-d860-11e6-80d5-066fd61aec22","resourceVersion":"197967","generation":5,"creationTimestamp":"2017-01-12T00:46:10Z","labels":{"k8s-app":"kube-controller-manager"},"annotations":{"deployment.kubernetes.io/revision":"1"}},"spec":{"replicas":0,"selector":{"matchLabels":{"k8s-app":"kube-controller-manager"}},"template":{"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"k8s-app":"kube-controller-manager"}},"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"secrets","secret":{"secretName":"kube-controller-manager","defaultMode":420}},{"name":"ssl-host","hostPath":{"path":"/usr/share/ca-certificates"}}],"containers":[{"name":"kube-controller-manager","image":"quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.4.7_coreos.0","command":["./hyperkube","controller-manager","--root-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/secrets/ca.crt","--service-account-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/secrets/service-account.key","--leader-elect=true","--cloud-provider=aws","--configure-cloud-routes=false"],"resources":{},"volumeMounts":[{"name":"secrets","readOnly":true,"mountPath":"/etc/kubernetes/secrets"},{"name":"ssl-host","readOnly":true,"mountPath":"/etc/ssl/certs"}],"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent"}],"restartPolicy":"Always","terminationGracePeriodSeconds":30,"dnsPolicy":"Default","securityContext":{}}},"strategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate","rollingUpdate":{"maxUnavailable":1,"maxSurge":1}},"revisionHistoryLimit":0,"paused":true},"status":{"observedGeneration":3}}
I0112 17:33:54.335302   44607 round_trippers.go:296] GET https://k8s-k8s.westfield.io:443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/deployments/kube-controller-manager
```

And then times out
saying that it timed out waiting for an api response.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.7", GitCommit:"92b4f971662de9d8770f8dcd2ee01ec226a6f6c0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-10T04:49:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.7+coreos.0", GitCommit:"0581d1a5c618b404bd4766544bec479aedef763e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-12-12T19:04:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I originally had client version 1.5.2 Downgraded to see if that helps. It didn't.

Answer (score 2):

A replication controller defines what a pod looks like and how many replicas should exist in your cluster. The controller-manager's job is to make sure enough replicas are healthy and running, if not then it will ask the scheduler to place the pods onto hosts.

If you delete a pod, then a new one should get spun up automatically. You would just have to run: `kubectl delete po <podname>`

It's interesting that you are trying to delete the controller manager. typically after creating that, you shouldn't have to touch it.

Comment: I was customizing some of those manifests and now I simply want to redeploy them. There should be no obstacle for me to do it. Anyways, redeployed the cluster by now. Thanks for clarification on how the parts communicate though.

Answer (score 0):

You can  delete a replication controller using following command:

```
kubectl delete rc kube-controller-manager
```